# Custom macOS-like character shortcuts in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, x11

I would like to make combination `Alt-x` to input symbol `×` (U+00D7).

It should be implemented at level as low as possible: using X11 utilities is good, using KDE/Gnome utilities is bad.

It must not interfere with keyboard layout and work with every one of them.

It must behave exactly as I described in first line.
Using compose key to input `Alt`, then `x` and `x` is not a solution.

I achieved some progress with *xmodmap*, however I do not know if it is a dead end or not:

`xmodmap -e 'keycode 53 = x X U00D7 U00D7'` does the trick, but interferes with keyboard layout. In fact it overrides it.

`xmodmap -e 'keycode 53 = x X ч Ч U00D7 U00D7` breaks layout too. [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap) says that it defines symbols for *AltGr* modifier (and no clue how to bind it to Alt). [Manual](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/xmodmap.1.html) does not say anything about 5th and 6th entries at all.

Comment: You can assign keys to virtual modifiers (AltGr etc) with setxkbmap. In general there is no way to remap keys the way you want by playing with configuration files. You can create an entirely new keyboard layout with Xkb if you want. Note that remapping the Alt-x combination will break quite a few programs.